# problems with php newline

Tags: php, newline

I have this code

```
if($hgroup['groupid'] == $row_groups['groupid']){
  $problem++;
  $hostname=DBfetch($cursor_gethost_again);
  $replace_macro=array('/{HOSTNAME}/','/{HOST.NAME}/');
  $problem_text=$problem_text.$trigger['description'];
  $problem_text=preg_replace($replace_macro,$hostname['name'],$problem_text);
  $problem_text=$problem_text."\r\n";
}
```

It is a code generating in cycle. Can anybody help me how to make that stupid newline? I have to do it this way because I'm modifying one code. So I want to keep that layout. 
 It doesn't work. It will print it with text. I also try preg_replace to `<br />`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't full understand you. What are you wanting done with the newline?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding just what you're asking here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to print out HTML, the new line is not using `\r\n` but by appending `<br/>`.

In a comment you confirmed that you were trying to view this in a browser. As Kolink said, browsers collapse whitespaces to a space, so you lose your new line information.

If you were to output the value to a standard output, like the console, then `\r\n` are the solution. Same thing if you are dealing with a file you want to write to.

If you wanted to output it both to a standard output AND then in HTML, I'd suggest first filling it with `\r\n`, output your variable, then use `str_replace` (documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)) to convert all your `\r\n` to `<br/>`:

```
$html_problem_text = str_replace('\r\n', '<br/>', $problem_text);
```

Comment: so :) i think im retarded. I was doing my debug with alert box. There was everything ok with line breaks. Then i was thinking that there is css problem. I have white-space property inherited from somewhere and white-space : pre-wrap; did the trick. But thanks for help anyway :* im just bit retarded and overworked :D

Answer (score 3):

Just throwing a guess out there, are you viewing the output in a browser? Because browsers collapse newline characters (or anywhitespace) into a single (horizontal) space.

You need to use the `<br />` tag to create a newline in the browser, or you could use `<pre>` or some CSS to force the browser to render newlines as such.

Comment: As i said i was trying to replace it somehow. When i come home i will try that function. And yes i am viewing this ij browser. But it accepted \n but it just wont break

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

```
\n = CR (Carriage Return) // new line character in Unix
\r = LF (Line Feed) // new line character in Mac OS
\n\r = CR + LF // new line character in Windows
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are printing out in HTML:

You can use:

```
$problem_text=$problem_text."<br/>";
```

Or keep the `$problem_text=$problem_text."\r\n";` if you want but when outputting, do:

```
nl2br($myvariable);
```

This functions is basically "new line to br", it replaces the new line to `<br/>` so you don't need to have the `"<br/>"` in your variable.

Also for your information you can use `".="` that means "concatenate this text to the variable:

```
$problem_text=$problem_text."\r\n";
$problem_text .= "\r\n";
```

They mean the same, by same rule there are other operators like += or -= for arithmetic operations (.= is only for concatenating strings).